# "required is not defined" in packaged AWS Lambda Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am attempting my first packaged AWS Lambda function which is currently failing and returning "required is not defined" in the logs.

Initially in the function, I am looking to just get a simple node command to return a json file from a Google Sheet using an npm module. From my ec2 instance which has `gsjson` installed, this is very easy. I just type:

```
gsjson 1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8 fruits.json
```

[![EC2 NodeJS - gsjson][1]][1]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsjson

The packaged zip file I uploaded contains an index.js file and a node modules folder containing the google-spreadsheet-to-json npm module from GitHub.

Here is the index.js code:

```
var gsjson = require('google-spreadsheet');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    'gsjson 1KIg84G9CXErw2bWhkEHWUkOI4CR-biFeLqCtdypaLU8 fruits.json';
}
```

**UPDATE**: After adjusting the typo, the error message is now

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'google-spreadsheet'",
```

**UPDATE 2 - SUCCESS**: Although the npm module is called gsjson and npm folder google-spreadsheet-to-json. The require must reference "google-spreadsheet". Edited code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`required` is not defined because you did not define it. Plus I hope you meant `require`. You can look at [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more info.

```
var gsjson = require('google-spreadsheet-to-json');
```

Comment: Hi Arpit, No it's definetely 'required'. Here is the error output from 'Details' within Lambda after running the test https://pastebin.com/Yxmxs94g

Comment: There is nothing like required in nodejs. If you want to import something then you have to use `require`

Comment: Ah ok, looks like a typo. I've changed to require and now getting errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'google-spreadsheet

Comment: For that you have to ask another question. Your original question is answered. I suggest you accept this one and ask another one. I will be happy to help you there.

Comment: Hi Arpit, If you are still interested. Here was the follow on question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074910/create-a-file-in-tmp-and-upload-to-s3-aws-lambda